# How to distribute IOS apps to end users without knowing their UDID?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-distribution

I am unable to upload my app to app store. The app is meant for a particular client and it manages a particular occasion of theirs. There are quite a few features. It gets rejected with the message- 'Minimum functionality. This app is meant for a small set of users'. Apple asks me to use the ad hoc method of distribution. However that is not a feasible option as I can't have access to all the UDIDs of the users. How can I distribute the app to the end users? Please help me out.

Comment: If the users are all employees of a single company, then custom app distribution is probably most appropriate.  You can use enterprise distribution as Sven suggests, but that has its own complexity and increased costs.  If the users are not all employees of the same company then there is no real solution

Answer (score 0):

That’s what the Enterprise Developer Program is for. With that you can sign In-House apps so that they can be installed on any device. You’re just not allowed to distribute such apps to the general public. According to the rules your client will have to subscribe to that program.